# Fire Key event from chrome extension: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to fire key events when clicking on a chrome extension button.

manifest:

```
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["a.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "input"
  ],
  ...
```

a.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  ...
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "script.js"
  });
});
```

script.js

```
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {bubbles : false, cancelable : true, key : "Left"});
var e2 = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {bubbles : false, cancelable : true, key : "Left"});
chrome.input.ime.sendKeyEvents({contextId:0, keyData:[e, e2]}, function() {console.log("callback");});
```

What the console prints is:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ime' of undefined*

Im on Chrome 35 / Ubuntu 12.04

Thank you!

Comment: What is manifest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that `chrome.input.ime` API is not available to Content Scripts, like most Chrome APIs.

You must operate it from the background script.